# Moving a package file of UIDocument class to iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument, nsfilewrapper

I'm writing an app which saves and loads documents both locally and on iCloud. Locally is working fine, but I'm having a problem with iCloud.

The documents are saved as a package - the UIDocument reads and writes an NSFileWrapper which contains an image file, a thumbnail file, and an info plist. When I save the document to iCloud and then look at the files under 'Manage Storage', I see the individual files instead of the packages; and more importantly when I search for files using NSMetadataQuery it returns an NSMetadataItem for each of the individual files instead of the packages. As a result, my app doesn't realise there are any packages to load and iCloud is pretty useless.

I thought that if I set up the document type and exported the UTI correctly that the packages would be treated properly. Was that right? If so, what's the checklist for setting up a document type as a package?

Comment: Same problem here. Something must be wrong with the document definition… I'm still investigating.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did add com.apple.package to the "Exported UTIs" and also to Document Types ("Types" field). Though I do not have an icon, is the icon required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fixed this issue by adding an object (add com.apple.package) in conforms to UTIs array (in plist file)

Comment: Perhaps accept your own answer if that is possible? So that other people know that this was the correct solution.